# Drop down value could not selected while changing using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing one issue. I am setting the drop down value dynamically but while changing to other value its not happening using Jquery. I am explaining my code below.

```js
var selectedText2 = 'Active';
$("#cmbStatus option").each(function() {
  if ($(this).html() == selectedText2) {
    $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
    return;
  }
});

function getStatus() {
  console.log('status', $("#cmbStatus").val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control tooltips" id="cmbStatus" name="cmbStatus" title="Pick Status">
  <option value="1">Active</option>
  <option value="0">Inactive</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="centreaddsave" onclick="getStatus();">Save</button>
```

Here I am setting value(`i.e-Active`) dynamically. but when I am changing value to `Inactive` and clicked on save button again value is showing as `1` means its not changing. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: It works actually.

Comment: Do you have your jQuery code at the bottom of your `<body>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

For more clarification use the same code as follows

```
 var selectedText2 = '0';
    $("#cmbStatus").val(selectedText2);
```

Please try to use the value part instead of the Html to set the initial value of a dropdown.

And then Get status

```
function getStatus() {
  console.log('status', $("#cmbStatus").val());
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: The OP's code actually works, so what do you hope that you answer will solve?

Comment: Just trying to propose a better solution. (As setting initial value using the drop down content instead of the value seems a bad practice)